# Wicket implementation of bootstrap-wysiwyg

Tags: java, wicket

Im trying to figure out how to create a wicket component wicket could represent a div that is then used by the [Bootstrap-wyiswyg](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg) javascript. Once the page is submitted i want to be able to get the content of the div and have that represented on the server, in a `IModel<String>`.

The part im struggling with is getting the content from the div to the server-side. For instance if i used a textarea i would just have my component `extends TextArea` and that would do all of this for me. So really what im asking is whether there is a wicket component that i can add as a `<div wicket:id="mycomponent"></div>` but onsubmit populate the component's Model with the content of the div from the client-side. Or do I have to write all this code myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a normal "wicket" textarea to your form (with `display: none`) and add a jQuery handler for the form's submit event that will do something like:

```
$('your-text-area-selector').html($('your-wysiwyg-div-selector').html());
```

Comment: Sounds like that will do the job, i'll try it out tonight and mark as answered afterward, Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! Keep in mind that you can extend a TextArea component that will always add a behavior appending the binding javascript code on after render if you want to have it in a more efficient way.